# Good ways to change Icons in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, icons, themes

I'm looking for a good, preferably fast way to change icons in Windows XP. I've found a few methods, but they weren't exactly efficient.

EDIT: to clarify, I'm looking for alternatives similar to [this.](http://www.stardock.com/products/iconpackager/)

Comment: Which icons do you mean?

Comment: Folder icons, system icons, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) without a doubt. For folder icons the functionality is already built in, right-click the folder and go to the customize tab, then click "change icon":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a program like [xpize](http://www.xpize.net/)?

Comment: I already use that, but it's a great application.

Answer (score 0):

[iColorFolder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icolorfolder/)(allowing to change the color of Windows XP folders, with a simple right-click on them.) is what i guess you are looking for.